# std::stack<T> causing segfaults while debugging in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, std

So I've been fighting with the std::stack libraries for the last day or so. I'm trying to debug some code of mine, and rather than doing things by pen and paper, I'm using the eclipse debugger.

The first weird thing, is that if I have an expressions relating to the stack in the eclipse expressions window, the program will die as soon as I start it.

The other thing, is that the first time it ran, the debugger saw the stack fine. I could inspect its elements through the expressions window. But as soon as I pushed something onto the stack, the stack.top() method started returning an error in the expression window. Then if  I try to step the program, it just dies. This isn't the behavior when its running without the debugger, so I'm really at a loss here.

Here's the problem code:

All I need to do is hit step over, and Eclipse opens a window from the stl_deque.h file, and then I hit step return and it dies.

```
int main() {
    std::stack<Cell> path;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you've shown us enough code to find the bug. Specifically, I think we at least need the other `findSln` function.

Comment: The bug isn't occurring there. Consider the other findSln to be a placeholder.

Comment: As soon as something is pushed onto the stack, the errors start. Or if I leave the expressions in the expression window in Eclipse, the program won't even run. The program isn't even running the other method at the moment.

Comment: Then we most likely aren't being shown the code that has the bug. Can you give me a link to complete, compilable code, and test input, that replicates the problem?

Comment: the code for the second findSln is now: 

return;

And the problem still occurs. Like I said, the bug isn't occurring there.

Comment: even commenting out the first findSln in main reproduces the problem.. the problem is not in my code.. there's either something wrong with the debugger, or with eclipse, or god forbid the stl.. im just hoping someone has encountered something similar

Comment: Then paste the simplest, compilable code that reproduces the bug. The more things you can rule out, the better. The problem will have to be in what's left.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll edit the above in a sec

Comment: What are `M` and `N`?

Comment: M and N are constant array dimensions.

Comment: Above edited, and I can still reproduce the issues. I'm in the process of trying another IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine (at least, the part of your code you've shown us). The problem you're describing is simply that *the Eclipse debugger* crashes when you try to evaluate `stack.top()` in it. This is a bug in Eclipse (specifically in its built-in support for inspecting C++ container types), and it's not something you can easily fix yourself.

One possible workaround would be to add debugging functions to your own code; for example

```
const Cell *stackTop(const std::stack<Cell> *stk)
{ return &stk->top(); }
```

Then whenever you want to get at `stack.top()` in your debugging session, type in `*stackTop(&stack)` instead. Notice that this definition of `stackTop` avoids dealing with templates, inlining, references, *and* move-semantics — all of which are things with which I would expect the average debugger to have trouble — instead it's just a single non-templated function that takes a pointer and returns a pointer. It would take a very stupid debugger to get confused by this simple of a function.

If Eclipse can successfully inspect `std::vector<Cell>` without crashing, then you might consider rewriting your code to use `vector` instead of `stack`; [this will likely be more efficient anyway.](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque/)

Comment: so after a little more experimentation, including with other IDE's (netbeans, codelite), i've concluded that GDB must not like calling methods from template classes.. so you're right.. 

i went so far as to define my own stack class using templates..

but the method above works great

Comment: Glad I could help. I hope you also learned something about writing good bug reports, from the comments on your question. ;) A good workman doesn't often blame his tools, but if your tools are *crashing*, that's one case where you *should* blame them, and not confuse the issue by posting dozens of lines of your own code. :)

Comment: Thanks yeah! I really wasn't sure what was causing the issue. I'm still a learning programmer, and c++ isn't my strong suit, so sometimes there are minor mistakes in my code that aren't immediately apparent. But you're right, after some experimentation it was clear what was causing the crash.